# Show that the given transformation is linear, by showing it is a matrix transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

the transformation states this: P projects a vector onto the line y=x.

First: I'm not sure how to set this up. my first approach is to say:

$$F\left[\begin{matrix} x\\ y  \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix} x=y\\ \end{matrix}\right]$$

after this its a lost cause for me. I know that to find the stadard matrix you can take the transformation and insert the standard bases, but I'm not sure how this would get the standard matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a basis of the space, formed from by the vector $(1,1)$ and a vector perpendicular to it, such as $(-1,1)$.

For any $v$, you can write $v = a(1,1) + b(-1,1)$ for some $a,b$. 
Then, you can prove that $P(v) = a(1,1)$ (this is because you should have both $P(v) - v \perp (1,1)$ and $P(v) \parallel (-1,1)$).

From this, you can prove

- that it is a linear transformation
- that the matrix of this linear transformation in the basis $\{
  (1,1), (-1,1)
  \}$ is
  \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 1
  \end{pmatrix}

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. I understand that a basis is a subset that contains vectors that span a larger vector space, have a linearly independent set of vectors and create a unique combination. But I don't understand how that fits into this problem.

Comment: @Joshhw a linear application is characterized by its values on a basis.

Comment: I was under the impression it it relied on the standard basis. That I somehow had to use the standard vectors within the transformation to find the standard matrix, but I can't see the setup. where does the orthogonal property play into this?

Comment: @Joshhw it is related to the definition of the projection.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the matrix by seeing where the two vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ map to.  For $(1,0)$ you need to find the line that goes through $(1,0)$ that is orthogonal to the line $y=x$.  Then find the point of intersection with that line and $y=x$.  Do the same for $(0,1)$.  Then the first column of the matrix will be the image of $(1,0)$ and the second column will be the image of $(0,1)$.

Comment: this does not prove that the tranformation is linear.

Comment: @mookid I figured I could get him the matrix and he could do the rest by showing what $(x,y)$ maps to for arbitrary $x$ and $y$ and checking it with the matrix.  It seemed like this was homework.